# How to search Github repositories which have file with particular filename?

Tags: github, github-api

E.g.: I want to find all CRMs which have `Dockerfile` inside their repository.

I checked [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/), but haven't found any suitable search qualifier. There is just `filename:` and `in:file:`, but it's not as desired, I need something like `has_file:` or `in:filename`

Any workaround?

Comment: I don't understand. Why `filename:dockerfile` doesn't satisfy ? It shows all repositories with dockerfile in them.

Comment: Because it doesn't work. Please check two search queries - [1](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=CRM&s=stars&type=Repositories) and [2](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=CRM+filename%3ADockerfile&s=stars&type=Repositories), number of results is same

Comment: can you please check this query https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=CRM+filename%3ADockerfile&s=stars&type=code

Comment: This query search code, not repositories

Answer (score 4):

The best workaround for this purpose is ..

search using `in:path Dockerfile`

This will also include directories consisting the word 'Dockerfile', but such results are quite unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through [GitHub search reference](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/#search-based-on-the-contents-of-a-repository), it clearly states:

> You can find a repository by searching for content in its README file, using the *in:readme* qualifier.
>   Besides using *in:readme*, it's **not possible** to find repositories by searching for specific content within the repository. To search for a specific file or content within a repository, you can use the file finder or code-specific search qualifiers.

File finder is not what you are looking for, so the only valid option is to [search for a code](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/).